# How to expand hovering on menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

[menu icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTBER.png)

I have added an icon using beavers menu module in wordpress . But when hover I want more space to the left of the icon, how do I do this?

My used css code:

```
.icon a{
padding-left: 20px !important;

background-image: url('/wp-content//uploads/image_ico.png');
background-size: 16px 16px;
background-position: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the hover on the element in question when you hover like this

```
.icon a{
padding-left: 20px !important;

background-image: url('/wp-content//uploads/image_ico.png');
background-size: 16px 16px;
background-position: left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.icon a:hover {
  padding-left: 40px !important;
}
```